# ConnMan: IPv4 online check failed for network

Tags: networkmanager

I am trying ConnMan on Arch Linux to replace NetworkManager.
I followed the ArchWiki and most of the things are fine, I can connect to 
wired network and psk wireless networks with ease. To connect to campus 
wireless eduroam network, I created config file `/var/lib/connman/eduroam.config`:

```
[service_eduroam]
Type=wifi
Name=eduroam
EAP=peap
CACertFile=/etc/ssl/certs/eduroam.cer
Phase2=MSCHAPV2
Identity=******@****
Passphrase=*********
```

It is strange that it doesn't work now although it actually worked quite well a few days ago when I started using it and added exactly this config.

The problem came from this line in the journal:
`connmand[1732]: IPv4 online check failed for 0x55e7a8216600 eduroam`. As a result, I can totally 
connect to eduroam but there is no internet.

I think the config is correct according to the settings provided 
by the university.

---

*Updates*

It turns out that eduroam is not the only network that connman has problem connecting. I have a wpa2 wireless network in the lab and I found that I cannot connect to it either and the journal has the same message `IPv4 online check failed`. This is strange because I have always been able to connect to this one until today.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a matter to asking the University and not here. Most likely, assuming nothing changed on your machine, the eduroam network could have not IP addresses to give you. We do not know the university configuration, and the config appears ok.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro if I switch back to NetworkManager eduroam works, so I doubt that it is problem of the network.

Comment: Since there is this problem in both eduroam and personal wpa2 networks, it must be something misconfigured on my laptop instead of anything about the networks. I hope some people here could give some hints and be helpful. Thank you :)